# Defining Entites/Intents in Microsoft LUIS to fetch the right data from a MySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity, azure-language-understanding

we are creating a Chat-bot in C# for a university project that should be able to receive queries from a user in natural language, tries to understand them using LUIS.ai service from Microsoft, convert the JSON response from LUIS to a MySQL query, fetch the wanted information from the DB (osTicket system) and deliver the final result as a text, table or chart to the user.

The MySQl Database has many tables with information about users, tickets and staff....etc.
In short everything that is needed for a support ticket system.

The problem that we are facing now is that we don't know, what is the right approach to train LUIS correctly to help us with fetching the right data from the DB.

We tried at first to define everything (like table & table.column, e.g. ost_ticket.number) as simple entities in LUIS so that we get the wanted column directly (with enough training) but we faced a [limitation problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-resources-faq) with LUIS.

Now we are totally confused because we don't know how should we define the entities and the intents to get the most of LUIS.

Does anybody have an idea that might help us to define entities and intents in a reasonable way without exceeding the limits?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use normalization.

As I understand your problem, my answer for you is to use more entities with attributes and simplify them. I mean, store only the most required data in a table or entity. Use relations by primary and foreign key.

Also use **erd**(entity relationship diagram) for design of a database .

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment!
So you mean that we should create large joined tables like a mini version with all relevant (frequently asked) information and then define Entities that match these?
I think we might still hit the same problem with the limitation.
In LUIS FAQs it's mentioned that we should use (Lists, Hierarchical and Composite) Entities instead of many standard ones but we don't know what is the right method to do that.

P.S. we signed a non-disclosure agreement, so i cannot send you the code or the database.